# Files are undefined when submitting files to ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have got the following problem:

I am using ng-file-upload to post files to my backend.
I have setup the drop area to show up via ng-if when someone hit the a button.
This works perfectly I can select a file and I also see the name of it like in the demo of ng-file-upload.
The user should now be able to upload this file when hitting save but everytime he does that angular tells me that the files are undefined.

Here my upload and save method:

Upload:

```
  $scope.upload = function (files) {
        console.log($scope.files);
    if ($scope.files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            $upload.upload({
                url: base+'/doc/'+$scope.project_id+'?name='+$scope.doc.name,
                                    method: 'POST',
                doc: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                            evt.config.file.name);
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' +
                            JSON.stringify(data));
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Save:

```
$scope.saveDoc = function(){
    console.log($scope.files);
}
```

I cannot think of a reason why files should be empty since the ng-repeat in the frontend works.

```
<div ng-file-drop ng-file-select ng-model="files" class="drop-box"
      drag-over-class="dragover" ng-multiple="true" allow-dir="true">Drop pdfs or images here or click to upload</div>
  <div ng-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">{{f.name}}</li>
```

It shows me the name perfectly.

Comment: don't setup drop area with `ng-if` do use `ng-show` that will not create an new scope

Comment: I did try it with ng-show too did not fix it furthermore the whole area is inside another ng-if. Do you think that it is a problem or just a recommendation to use ng-show? I know that ng-show does not create another scope

Comment: yes, i'm sure that could be the issue because of ng-if only, if you do want to stay with ng-if then you need to use `$parent.` for all inner scope variables

Comment: I dont think that this is the problem. I have got a button which uses triggers a function which shows an area on my site via an ng-if. This area has got a save button which triggers a POST or GET for other data types. The only problem is with a file upload. I just send a or get a JSON from inside this ng-if it works perfectly.

Comment: could you tried to do `ng-model="$parent.files"`

Comment: No was not the problem